# Delaunay Triangulation half-working in p5

Tags: javascript, geometry, p5.js, triangulation, delaunay

I'm new to JavaScript (self-taught; writing in p5.js web editor) and my (possibly over-ambitious) goal is to write a script using the Bowyer-Watson method to triangulate a set of n points. I've been able to get all the components working independently, but I'm having trouble debugging what I'm seeing now that I'm not getting any errors. Here's my function (I know it's probably horribly organized, I'm still getting the hang of classes):

```js
function triangulate(A) {
  var E = []; //Edges set
  var T = []; //Triangles set
  var CCircles = []; //Circumcircle center points for Voronoi later

  if (A.length > 3) { //Handling edge cases
    var CHull = []; //Convex hull set
    var x_y_points = []; //Points converted to 2D array for convex hull function
    for (let i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
      let p = A[i];
      append(x_y_points, [p.x, p.y]);
    }
    convex_hull(x_y_points, CHull, [0, 255, 255, 25], [0, 255, 255, 100], false);

    //Create Super Triangle
    T[0] = super_triangle(A, CHull, T);
    let ST_a = T[0].a; //Save super triangle vertices for later
    let ST_b = T[0].b;
    let ST_c = T[0].c;

    //Bowyer-Watson
    for (let i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
      let p = A[i];
      let bad_triangles = [];

      for (let j = 0; j < T.length; j++) { // add all the points one at a time to the triangulation
        let t = T[j];

        if (t.circumcircle_check(p)) { // first find all the triangles that are no longer valid due to the insertion
          append(bad_triangles, t);
        }
      }

      let polygon = [];
      for (let j = 0; j < bad_triangles.length; j++) { // find the boundary of the polygonal hole
        let t1 = bad_triangles[j];

        for (let k = 0; k < t1.edges.length; k++) {
          let e1 = t1.edges[k];
          append(polygon, e1);

          for (let l = 0; l < bad_triangles.length; l++) {
            let t2 = bad_triangles[l];

            for (let m = 0; m < t2.edges.length; m++) { // remove shared edges of bad triangles
              let e2 = t2.edges[m];
              if (l != j) {
                if (e1.a === e2.a && e1.b === e2.b) {
                  shorten(polygon);
                  break;
                } else

                if (e1.b === e2.a && e1.a === e2.b) {
                  shorten(polygon);
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }

      for (let j = T.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) { 
        let t1 = T[j];
        for (let k = 0; k < bad_triangles.length; k++) { // remove bad triangles from data structure
          let t2 = bad_triangles[k];
          if (t1 === t2) {
            T.splice(j, 1);
          }
        }
      }

      for (let j = 0; j < polygon.length; j++) { // re-triangulate the polygonal hole
        let e = polygon[j];
        append(T, new Triangle(e.points[0], e.points[1], p));
      }
    }

    for (let its = 0; its < 3; its++) { // done inserting points, now clean up
      for (let i = 0; i < T.length; i++) {
        let t = T[i];
        for (let j = 0; j < t.points.length; j++) {
          let p = t.points[j];
          if (p === ST_a || p === ST_b || p === ST_c) {
            T.splice(i, 1);
          }
        }
      }
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < T.length; i++) {
      let t = T[i];
      append(E, t.edges[0]);
      append(E, t.edges[1]);
      append(E, t.edges[2]);
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < E.length; i++) {
      let e = E[i];
      for (let j = 0; j < e.points.length; j++) {
        let e_p = e.points[j];
        if (e.a === ST_a || e.a === ST_b || e.a === ST_c) {
          E.splice(i, 1);
        }
        if (e.b === ST_a || e.b === ST_b || e.b === ST_c) {
          E.splice(i, 1);
        }
      }
    }

    draw_triangles(T, 0, [255, 255, 0, 10], [255, 255, 0, 100], 1, true, CCircles);
    //draw_voronoi(CCircles, [255, 0, 0, 150], 1);
    draw_edges(E, [0, 255, 0, 255], 1);
    
    strokeWeight(1);
    stroke(255, 0, 0, 255);
    line(ST_a.x, ST_a.y, ST_b.x, ST_b.y);
    line(ST_b.x, ST_b.y, ST_c.x, ST_c.y);
    line(ST_c.x, ST_c.y, ST_a.x, ST_a.y);
  } else if (A.length > 2) {
    append(T, new Triangle(A[0], A[1], A[2]));
    append(E, T[0].edges[0]);
    append(E, T[0].edges[1]);
    append(E, T[0].edges[2]);
    draw_edges(E, [0, 255, 0, 255], 1);
    draw_triangles(T, 0, [255, 255, 0, 2], [255, 255, 0, 50], 1, false);
  } else if (A.length > 1) {
    append(E, [A[0], A[1]]);
    draw_edges(E, [0, 255, 0, 255], 1);
  }
  draw_points(A, [255, 255, 255, 255], 5);
}
```

I suspect my problem is one of data structures, as navigating them is something I'm not yet too familiar with. The problem I'm having is that, despite having no crossing edges or ridiculously thin triangles, not all of my edges are appearing and sometimes triangles in the middle of the triangulation get deleted during cleanup.

Edit: Link to code - https://editor.p5js.org/BasidiomyCody/sketches/n3lzBfRYq

Note that the green lines are edges, yellow fills are triangles, blue fill is the convex hull, red lines mark circum-circles and my super triangle

Comment: Can you provide working code or link to it, people shoudnt have to implement convex_hull to see what you are looking at

Comment: Mr_Nitrogen, good point. I've added a link at the bottom. Thanks